# How to add in PQT5 a event to a label

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlabel

My Probleme is i want to add to a label respectively text a event in my case the mousePressEvent.But it dont work under this text is some code from me that doesn´t work.

```
self.label2.mousePressEvent = self.credits

    def credits(self, event):
        print("credits")
```

Here i get the error AttributeError: 'Window' object has no attribute 'label2'

I also try this one:

```
label2.mousePressEvent.connect(self.credits)

def credits(self):
            print("credits")
```

That doenst work too :( Any Ideas i am glad if anybody can help me :(
if you need the full code here:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtGui import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initMe()

    def initMe(self):

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label1.setText("Überschrift mit namen des text adventure")
        label1.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label1.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label1.move(350,50)

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label2.setText("Spielen")
        label2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label2.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label2.move(450, 120)
        self.label2.mousePressEvent = self.spielen

        label3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label3.setText("Settings")
        label3.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label3.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label3.move(450, 200)
        self.label3.mousePressEvent = self.settings

        label4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self)
        label4.setText("Credits")
        label4.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label4.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label4.move(450, 280)
        self.label4.mousePressEvent = self.credits

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10 ))
        button = QPushButton("Spiel beenden", self)
        button.setGeometry(50,50,150,50)
        button.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        button.move(820, 420)
        button.setToolTip("<b>Button lel</b>")
        button.clicked.connect(QtCore.QCoreApplication.instance().quit)
        button.clicked.connect(self.gedruekt)
        button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        self.setGeometry(50,50,1000,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Gui lalal einhorn")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("cookie.png"))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")
        self.move(500, 250)
        self.show()

    def spielen(self, event):
        print("spielen")

    def settings(self, event):
        print("settings")

    def credits(self, event):
        print("credits")

    def gedruekt(self):
        print("Er hats getan ;(")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
else:
    print("Gui not created, because script used at liabary")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the variables are not members of the classes so it is not necessary to use the `self` instance, for this it changes for example:

```
self.label2.mousePressEvent = self.spielen
```

to:

```
label2.mousePressEvent = self.spielen
```

If you want to use connect, this is only for signals, for this we create a custom QLabel class like the following:

```
class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()
```

In this case you will be as follows:

```
class Label(QLabel):
    clicked = pyqtSignal()
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QLabel.__init__(self, parent=parent)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()

class Window(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initMe()

    def initMe(self):

        label1 = QLabel(self)
        label1.setText("Überschrift mit namen des text adventure")
        label1.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label1.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label1.move(350,50)

        label2 = Label(self)
        label2.setText("Spielen")
        label2.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label2.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label2.move(450, 120)
        label2.clicked.connect(self.spielen)

        label3 = Label(self)
        label3.setText("Settings")
        label3.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label3.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label3.move(450, 200)
        label3.clicked.connect(self.settings)

        label4 = Label(self)
        label4.setText("Credits")
        label4.setStyleSheet("font-size: 18px;color: black;")
        label4.setGeometry(50, 50, 400, 100)
        label4.move(450, 280)
        label4.clicked.connect(self.credits)

        QToolTip.setFont(QFont("Arial", 10 ))
        button = QPushButton("Spiel beenden", self)
        button.setGeometry(50,50,150,50)
        button.setFont(QFont("Arial", 12))
        button.move(820, 420)
        button.setToolTip("<b>Button lel</b>")
        button.clicked.connect(self.close)
        button.clicked.connect(self.gedruekt)
        button.setStyleSheet("background-color: white;")

        self.setGeometry(50,50,1000,500)
        self.setWindowTitle("Gui lalal einhorn")
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon("cookie.png"))
        self.setAutoFillBackground(True)
        self.setStyleSheet("background-color: lightblue;")
        self.move(500, 250)
        self.show()

    def spielen(self):
        print("spielen")

    def settings(self):
        print("settings")

    def credits(self):
        print("credits")

    def gedruekt(self):
        print("Er hats getan ;(")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: yeah thank you it works .This is my first programm inpython thats the reason why i am not so good ^^