# Assign function to word in QLabel

Tags: python, pyqt5

I am searching for a solution for the following problem:
I want to assign a function to a certain word inside a `QLabel` of `PyQt5`, so that when the word is clicked the function is executed.

```
    from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = "App"
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 700
        self.height = 300
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.setWindowTitle('Hauptmenü')

        self.central_widget = QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

        self.vbox = QVBoxLayout()

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.label_text = QLabel(self)
        text = "<a href='#'>Word1</a> and <a href='#'>Word2</a>"
        self.label_text.setText(text)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label_text)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.show()

        self.label_text.linkActivated.connect(self.function1)

    def function1(self):
        print("ja")

    def function2(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    demo = Window()
    demo.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

When clicking on `word1` and `word2` in the `QLabel` different functions should be executed. I don't know how to connect the `word2` to the second function.

Comment: Does it solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45239937/how-to-add-in-pqt5-a-event-to-a-label?

Comment: unfortunately not. I do not want to connect the whole label but only single words in the label

Comment: Oh, ok I get it. Can you provide a minimal setup to be usable by other people, please?

Comment: I added the minimal setup

Comment: I have extended the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `html` capabilities and `style` attribute to override default html link. Now when you click on `Word1` and `Word2`, `labelClicked` function received the anchor as parameter:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWidget
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        ...

    def initUI(self):
        self.label_text = QLabel(self)
        text = 'Here is the text with <a style="text-decoration:none; color:none" href="#word1">Word1</a> and here comes the <a style="text-decoration:none; color:none" href="#word2">Word2</a>'
        self.label_text.setText(text)
        self.label_text.linkActivated.connect(self.labelClicked)
        self.vbox.addWidget(self.label_text)
        self.central_widget.setLayout(self.vbox)
        self.show()

    def labelClicked(self, link):
        print(link)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
```

Comment: Finally you were closed of my answer :)

Comment: Thanks. That's exactly what I was looking for :)